# Как вывести на странице все исполняемые запросы к БД?

Tags: php, yii2

Во фреймворке есть debug panel, которая показывает огроомнейшее количество всех запросов, среди которых много служебных, для отладки, на сколько я понимаю.

Как мне вывести в конце страницы только те запросы, которые относятся к моей логике, которые непосредственно я написал,
а-ля

`SELECT * FROM "city" WHERE "id"=3`

`SELECT * FROM "location" WHERE "id" IN (2, 5)`

???

Потому что мне не нужна портянка запросов вида:

```
SELECT
    d.nspname AS table_schema,
    c.relname AS table_name,
    a.attname AS column_name,
    COALESCE(td.typname, tb.typname, t.typname) AS data_type,
    COALESCE(td.typtype, tb.typtype, t.typtype) AS type_type,
    a.attlen AS character_maximum_length,
    pg_catalog.col_description(c.oid, a.attnum) AS column_comment,
    a.atttypmod AS modifier,
    a.attnotnull = false AS is_nullable,
    CAST(pg_get_expr(ad.adbin, ad.adrelid) AS varchar) AS column_default,
    coalesce(pg_get_expr(ad.adbin, ad.adrelid) ~ 'nextval',false) AS is_autoinc,
    CASE WHEN COALESCE(td.typtype, tb.typtype, t.typtype) = 'e'::char
        THEN array_to_string((SELECT array_agg(enumlabel) FROM pg_enum WHERE enumtypid = COALESCE(td.oid, tb.oid, a.atttypid))::varchar[], ',')
        ELSE NULL
    END AS enum_values,
    CASE atttypid
         WHEN 21 /*int2*/ THEN 16
         WHEN 23 /*int4*/ THEN 32
         WHEN 20 /*int8*/ THEN 64
         WHEN 1700 /*numeric*/ THEN
              CASE WHEN atttypmod = -1
               THEN null
               ELSE ((atttypmod - 4) >> 16) & 65535
               END
         WHEN 700 /*float4*/ THEN 24 /*FLT_MANT_DIG*/
         WHEN 701 /*float8*/ THEN 53 /*DBL_MANT_DIG*/
         ELSE null
      END   AS numeric_precision,
      CASE
        WHEN atttypid IN (21, 23, 20) THEN 0
        WHEN atttypid IN (1700) THEN
        CASE
            WHEN atttypmod = -1 THEN null
            ELSE (atttypmod - 4) & 65535
        END
           ELSE null
      END AS numeric_scale,
    CAST(
             information_schema._pg_char_max_length(information_schema._pg_truetypid(a, t), information_schema._pg_truetypmod(a, t))
             AS numeric
    ) AS size,
    a.attnum = any (ct.conkey) as is_pkey,
    COALESCE(NULLIF(a.attndims, 0), NULLIF(t.typndims, 0), (t.typcategory='A')::int) AS dimension
FROM
    pg_class c
    LEFT JOIN pg_attribute a ON a.attrelid = c.oid
    LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef ad ON a.attrelid = ad.adrelid AND a.attnum = ad.adnum
    LEFT JOIN pg_type t ON a.atttypid = t.oid
    LEFT JOIN pg_type tb ON (a.attndims > 0 OR t.typcategory='A') AND t.typelem > 0 AND t.typelem = tb.oid OR t.typbasetype > 0 AND t.typbasetype = tb.oid
    LEFT JOIN pg_type td ON t.typndims > 0 AND t.typbasetype > 0 AND tb.typelem = td.oid
    LEFT JOIN pg_namespace d ON d.oid = c.relnamespace
    LEFT JOIN pg_constraint ct ON ct.conrelid = c.oid AND ct.contype = 'p'
WHERE
    a.attnum > 0 AND t.typname != ''
    AND c.relname = 'user'
    AND d.nspname = 'public'
ORDER BY
    a.attnum;
```

Comment: аля разберитесь как выводит эти запросы ваш фреймворк и дальше вам будет понятнее как сделать что бы выводил только ваши запросы

Comment: @madfan41k вот я не понимаю - что дальше?

Comment: Там есть фильтр, можно по телу запроса фильтрануть.

Comment: @fedornabilkin я не хочу фильтровать по телу запроса, с учетом того, что я не знаю какие эти тела могут быть в итоге, потому что activeQuery и всякие `withJoin` происходят. И фильтр сработает на один конкретный запрос, а я хочу видеть ВСЕ запросы на странице, которые писал я (через актив query или нет), но не служебные

Answer (score 0):

не знаю что там у вас за портянка, но обычный выхлоп дебага
[image: дебаг]

первый и последний обычно технические все остальное ваше

Comment: Вот увы, но как есть...например портянка кода, которую я выложил - ноги растут из `ActiveForm` и конкретно поля `$form->field($model, 'object_id')->textInput()`....не знаю почему. и такого добра много..... а вы можете выложить ваши кофигурационные файлы? А то на форуме *yii* мне сказали `enableSchemaCache ` включить и тогда служебные данные уйдут. но это не до конца меня избавило от данных ....может быть я что-то лишнего включил в конфигах, поэтому было бы неплохо взглянуть.

Comment: Похоже всё дело в `log` -> `traceLevel`

Comment: ```'log' => [
   'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
   'targets' => [
    [
     'class' => 'yii\log\DbTarget',
     'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
    ],
   ],
  ],```